# Arduino Float Value to Python using NRF24L01

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi3

Im trying to send temperature sensor data through NRF24L01 to Raspberry Pi and read it in Raspberry Pi using python. But the temperature sensor data comes to the Raspberry Pi as letters, which I found out is in Ascii values. Im not sure how to display the actual readings from the Arduino to the Raspberry Pi

Here is the Arduino code:

```
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include "printf.h"
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2

OneWire oneWire (ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

RF24 radio(9, 10);

void setup(void) {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensors.begin();
  radio.begin() ;
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX) ;
  radio.setChannel(0x76) ;
  radio.openWritingPipe(0xF0F0F0F0E1LL) ;
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads() ;
  radio.powerUp() ;
}

void loop(void) {
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  float temperature = sensors.getTempFByIndex(0);
  radio.write(&temperature, sizeof(float));
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print(sensors.getTempFByIndex(0));
}
```

Here is the code for Raspberry Pi in Python

```
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
pipes = [[0xE8, 0xE8, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1], [0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0, 17)

radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)

radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
radio.printDetails()
radio.startListening()

while True:

    while not radio.available(0):
        time.sleep(1/100)

    receivedMessage = []
    radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
    print("Received: {}".format(receivedMessage))

    print("Translating...")
    string = ""

    for n in receivedMessage:
        if (n >= 32 and n <= 126):
            string += chr(n)
    print("Our received message decodes to: {}".format(string))
```

I want to get the temperature value in numbers instead of letters. Instead of like this:

Translating ...
Our received message decodes to: N

Comment: What is the size of `receivedMessage` and what is the exact content of it after receiving (`radio.read`)?

Answer (score 0):

You should receive 4 bytes (On most architectures, `sizeof(float)` is always 4) so check your received data:

```
if (len(receivedMessage) == 4)
```

The four bytes represents a float so to convert it:

```
temperature = float.fromhex(''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in receivedMessage))
```

The four bytes is converted to an hex string and converted to a float.

Edit (not tested):

```
receivedMessage = []
radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())

if (len(receivedMessage) == 4)
   temperature = float.fromhex(''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in receivedMessage))
   print '%.2f' % temperature
```

Comment: You should care about the endianness byte order of the computer

Comment: @pytness  It is two ARM Cortex processors so I doubt the endianess would differ. But without the actual received data I can not confirm this.

Comment: @Gerhard thanks for replying. Im kind of new to coding, would you mind showing or telling me where to exactly put those lines of code to check the data size and converting it to float?